# Modifying timestamp of an uploaded file

Tags: box-api

I'm hoping to be able to retain the modification timestamp of a file I'm uploading through the API.  In the [API Doc](http://developers.box.com/docs/) section "Update a file’s information" it doesn't sound like the modification timestamp is a property of a file I can modify.  Is there another method that could achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are in the process of building this out as a new feature that will at first only be available via the V2 API.  You will have to wait a few weeks before we roll this out as a new feature.   Watch our developer blogs for the announcement.